# No network. Systemd-logind uses 60% CPU

Tags: network-manager, systemd

The network-manager doesn't work. I can boot, but only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> gives me a terminal. When I try to login into the Windows-System, I get back the info that Systemd-logind uses 60% of the resources.

Any tips how I can debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> still gives you a console login.

With no network manager your `systemd` could be wasting time waiting for it to come up. After logging into the console use this command:

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Then reboot.

If you find out later you need the service at boot time use:

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```